# SfB Mute Individual Chats

Tags: windows-10, chat, lync, mute, skype-for-business

I understand this question has been asked before, but I believe I may be using a separate version of Skype than the rest of those asking and being answered.

I would like to mute new message alerts for our group conversation but maintain alerts for the rest of my chats open. Two solutions were discovered with my search:

> 1 - Chat commands
>
> > This is not working for me. The command has no spaces before it but it only shows as text. This leads me to believe that perhaps there is a setting within Skype to disable this feature. If not, perhaps this feature is not offered within Skype for Business as it is within regular Skype.
>
> 2 - Adjust sound options for this particular window
>
> > This is not available to me as my sound options are locked down along with most of the rest of my options. We have very limited permissions on our workstations.

The version we are currently using is Skype for Business 2016 MSO (16.0.8431.2046) on Windows 10 Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

I found a forum post discussing the 'chat' tab for SFB but it appears the solution we are looking for only works for SFB 2015 with a local domain server (e.g. not SFB cloud) or to use yammer:

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1690824-workaround-for-persistent-chat-on-o365-skype-for-business